# Exporting from Blender to Unreal engine 5

Tags: export, import, unreal-engine

I have a question when exporting from Blender to Unreal my colors are not the same as in Blender and thhe UV effects added are not kept. Is there any way to fix this? On the left is the object imported in Unreal and on the right the obj in blender. Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdlfy.jpg

I tried exporting in multiple ways but none of them work.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)